# Alert aparecendo na hora errada

Tags: php, html, alert, bdd

Fiz um código php onde a primeira parte dele é passar pela pagina login.php. e para isso coloquei um alert para avisar quando o login e senha forem incorretos. para isso coloquei um If e um else e deixei o alert dentro do Else, porem ao entrar na pagina a primeira coisa que faz é mostrar a janelinha do alert com a massagem a qual coloquei e sempre que atualizo a pagina a janelinha do alert aparecer, sendo que eu quero fazer o alert aparecer apenas quando o login ou senha forem incorreto. abaixo segue os códigos usados.

Login.php

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');


window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function funcao(x) {
    x.style.background = "#B22222";
}
</script>

</head>
<body id="imgpos">
    <center>
  <h2 title="nao fique parado!">Sistema Controle de Produtos</h2>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.
display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.
display='block'" style="width:auto;">Cadastro</button>
</center>
 <div id="id01" class="modal">
  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action ="" method = "post" >
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="fechar">&times;</span>
     <img src="4ad.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Login:</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu usuario" name="login" required onfocus ="funcao(this)">

      <label><b>Senha:</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha" name="senha" required required minlength="8" maxlength="8" onfocus ="funcao(this)">
        
      <button type="submit">Entrar!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#7FFFD4">
      <center>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="id02" class="modal">
  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action ="evento2.php?cadastro=true" method = "post" >
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="voltar">&times;</span>
     <img src="25.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Login:</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o usuario desejado" name="login1" required onfocus ="funcao(this)">

      <label><b>Senha:</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Digite a senha desejada" name="senha1" required minlength="8" maxlength="8" onfocus ="funcao(this)">
        
      <button type="submit">Cadastrar!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#7FFFD4">
      <center>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">voltar</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<h3 align="center">&copy Amem!</h3>
<?php
include_once "conexao.php";
if(isset($_POST['login']))$login = $_POST['login'];
if(isset($_POST['senha']))$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$sql="select * from funcionario where nome='$login' and senha='$senha'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$res=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($res){
 $linha=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['id']=$linha['id_funcionario'];
 $_SESSION['nome']=$linha['nome'];
 echo "<script> window.location='index.php'</script>";  
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Login ou Senha invalidos')</script>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['id'])==0 and isset($_SESSION['nome'])==0){
  echo "<script> window.location='login.php'</script>";
}else{
  $nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
  echo "<h3>usuario: $nome <a href='login.php'>sair</a></h3>";
}
?>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function valida_preco() {
   var num = document.getElementById('preco').value;
   if ( isNaN( num ) ) { // isNaN = is not a number
      alert('Não é um número!');
      return false;
   }
   return true; // prossegue o envio
}
</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <TITLE>Cadastros</TITLE>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#horario tbody tr:odd").addClass("zebraum");
});
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#horario tbody tr:even").addClass("zebradois");
});
    $(function(){
        $("#valor").maskMoney();
    })
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY id="imgpos">
<center>
  <h2 title="nao fique parado!">Controle de Estoque!</h2>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.
display='block'" style="width:auto;">Cadastra-se</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.
display='block'" style="width:auto;">Registros</button>
</center>
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action ="evento.php?cadastro=true" method = "post" >
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="fechar">&times;</span>
     <img src="5534.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Produto:</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o nome do Produto" name="produto" required onfocus ="funcao(this)">

      <label><b>Preço:</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="valor" placeholder="R$..." name="preco" required onfocus ="funcao(this)">
        
      <button type="submit">Cadastrar!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#7FFFD4">
      <center>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
    <div id="id02" class="modal">

    <form class="modal-content animate" action ="evento.php?cadastro=true" method = "post" >
        <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Voltar">&times;</span>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
      
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#7FFFD4">
      <center> <h2>Lista de Produtos 
</h2></center>
 <table border="2" id='horario'>
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Produto</th>
  <th>Preço</th>
  <th>Funcionário</th>
  <th>Alterar</th>
  <th>Excluir</th>
</tr>
<style type="text/css">
  tbody tr:hover{background-color:#555} 

</style>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6"><center><script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    dayName = new Array ("domingo", "segunda", "terça", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sábado")
monName = new Array ("janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "agosto", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro")
now = new Date
document.write (" Hoje é " + dayName[now.getDay() ] + ", " + now.getDate () + " de " + monName [now.getMonth() ]   +  " de "  +     now.getFullYear () + "   ")
document.write ( + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds() )
</script></center></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<center>
 <?php
            include_once "conexao.php";
            $sql = "select p.codigo, p.nome as np, p.preco, c.nome as nf from funcionario as c join produto as p on
            c.id_funcionario=p.id_funcionario";
            $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            if($result){
            while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tbody id="horario">
       <tr>
           <td id='p3'> <?php  echo $linha['codigo'];?></td>
           <td> <?php echo $linha['np'];?></td>
           <td id='p4'> <?php echo "R$". $linha['preco'];?></td>
           <td> <?php echo $linha['nf'];?></td>       
           <td> <?php echo "<a id='p1' href = editar.php?editar=".$linha['codigo']." >editar </a>";?></td>
           <td> <?php echo "<a id='p2' href = evento.php?deletar=".$linha['codigo'].">excluir</a>";?></td>
       </tr>
</tbody>

<?php
          }//fim do while
          }//fim do if  
          mysql_close($con);
?>
</table> 
    <center>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">voltar</button>
       </center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');


window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function funcao(x) {
    x.style.background = "#B22222";
}
</script>
<h3 align="center">&copy Amem!</h3>
<BR>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

conexao.php

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Conexao</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
  $host="localhost";
  $login="root";
  $senha="";
  $banco="controle_de_estoque";

  $con=mysql_connect($host,$login,$senha)or die("Erro ao conecta!".mysql_error());
  $sql="create database if not exists ".$banco;
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
  mysql_select_db($banco,$con);
  $sql = "create table if not exists funcionario(
  id_funcionario int(8) auto_increment,
  nome varchar(100) not null,
  senha varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(id_funcionario))";
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
  $sql="create table if not exists produto(codigo int(8) auto_increment,
  nome varchar(100) not null, preco varchar(15) not null, id_funcionario int(8) not null,
  primary key(codigo), foreign key(id_funcionario) references funcionario(id_funcionario))";
  mysql_query($sql);
?>

</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

editar.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <?php
    include_once 'conexao.php';
    $sql='select * from produto where codigo='.$_GET['editar'];
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $linha=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
        $("#valor").maskMoney();
    })
</script>

<body>
<center>
<div id="id01" class="modal" >
    </center>
  <form class="modal-content animate"<?php echo "<form action= 'evento.php?editar=".$linha['codigo']."'method='post'";?>>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="window.location='index.php'" class="close" title="fechar">&times;</span>
     <img src="5534.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container"><br>
      Produto:<br>
         <input type="text" name="produto" value="<?php echo $linha['nome'];?>" required><p></p>
        Preço:<br>
         <input type="text" id="valor" name="preco" value="<?php echo $linha['preco'];?>" required><p></p>
         <br>
      <button type="submit">Editar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#7FFFD4">
        <center>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location='index.php'" class='cancelbtn'>Cancel</button>
        </center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

evento.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['id'])==0 and isset($_SESSION['nome'])==0){
  echo "<script> window.location='login.php'</script>";
}else{
  $userId=$_SESSION['id'];
  $nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
}

 include_once'conexao.php';
 if(isset($_POST['produto']))$atrProduto = $_POST['produto'];
 if(isset($_POST['preco']))$atrPreco = $_POST['preco'];
 if(isset($_GET['cadastro']))
 {


$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `produto` SET `nome` = \"%s\", `preco` = \"%s\", `id_funcionario` = \"%d\";",
    $atrProduto,
    $atrPreco,
    $userId);

 mysql_query($sql,$con);
 echo "<script>alert('Produto cadastrado com sucesso!')</script>";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['deletar'])){
 $sql = "delete from produto where codigo = ".$_GET['deletar'];
 mysql_query($sql,$con);
 echo "<script>alert('Produto deletado com sucesso!')</script>";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['editar'])){
 $sql = "update produto set nome= '".$atrProduto."',preco='".$atrPreco."', id_funcionario=".$userId." where codigo=".$_GET['editar'];
 mysql_query($sql,$con);
 echo"<script> alert('Produto atualizado com sucesso')</script>";
 }
 echo"<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar meu erro, do porque o alert sempre funcionar assim que entro na pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, faz essas alterações no seu código.

```
if($_POST['login'] && $_POST['senha']){
      $email = $_POST['login'];
      $password = $_POST['senha'];
      $sql="SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$password'";
      $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
      $res=mysql_num_rows($result);
      if($res){
        $linha=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id']=$linha['id_funcionario'];
        $_SESSION['nome']=$linha['nome'];
        echo "<script> window.location='index.php'</script>";   
      }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Login ou Senha invalidos')</script>";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou, fico muito agradecido, tanto por me ajudar como por me fazer aprender mais ainda sobre a linguagem